# SharePoint Item Changed or Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers, designer

I have a requirement where certain actions take place after status change.Status list contains 10 items.Which will be the best and efficient way to implement if loop in SharePoint designer workflow(Item Changed) or event receiver(Item Updated)?

Please Help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on what you want to do after this is triggered. Workflow is always a much easier approach, unless you need to do some stuff that is not possible to achieve using a workflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This totally depends on your requirement. Please refer following points this will be helpful for your decision.

1. If you need the ability to cancel the process, you should use Event Receiver. It is not possible to cancel the action(update/delete/add) in Workflows.
2. If input is require from user or you need any kind of user interaction then you should go for workflow.
3. If the process takes longer time to resolve then workflow is more appropriate than an event receiver.
4. You have ability to manually trigger the Workflow if require.
5. Workflows are better if the amount of data is less. Whereas Event Receivers are best suited for large amount of data.

Comment: Please check this MSDN article for your reference - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648492.aspx

Comment: whether large amount of data implies no of list items or list fields?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow on ItemUpdated.

For simple if conditions, a SP2010 workflow will work just fine. For advanced looping and/or API calls, then SP2013 workflow will be required. Avoid the Event Receiver if possible.

Comment: Could you please explain why Event Receiver should be avoided? Whether it  causes any performance issues?

Comment: Event Receivers can be fine and the performance both of an Event Receiver and Workflow are dependent on the tasks you are performing and how you do them. I *suggest* avoiding them because Event Receivers require server side code, a deployment package, and are not supported in O365 *(However, Remote Event Receivers are, but these are even more complex)*. Workflows are generally much simpler to create and maintain and unless you have a strong case for why they won't work, they're usually your best best - Especially when talking about 10 list items, a single updated event, and a small loop.